# Radian 6 customised query for historical data

Tags: twitter, radian6

I am a radian 6 user and I am looking at getting historical twitter measures (tweets,followers,following data) for many twitter handles at once. Currently i can get the data from Radian 6 but I need to do it one by one and not at once and this takes a lot of time. Any help on this would be very much appreciated.